# Using JavaScript create a div and also it will come top of the main div

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML template.

```
<div id='main'>
  <div id='1'>one</div>
</div>
```

I want dynamically create a new div with inside of main div and also it (new div>) will come to top of the main div. The answer look likes

```
<div id='main'>
  <div id='new'>new</div>
  <div id='1'>one</div>
</div>
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [jQuery's `.prepend()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) when selecting the `#main` element.

```
$('#main').prepend('<div id="new">new</div>');
```

You should note that it is not valid HTML4 to have an ID that starts with a number. So `id="1"` wouldn't be valid.

Changing it to a valid id like `id="div_1"`, you could select that and use [jQuery's `.before()` method](http://api.jquery.com/before/) instead.

```
$('#div_1').before('<div id="new">new</div>');
```

And in either case, remember to wrap your jQuery code like this so that it doesn't run until the DOM is ready.

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').prepend('<div id="new">new</div>');
});
```